# Is this NP complete?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

I have to say that I am newbie in graph theory, so bear with me.
Here is my question:

Assume that you are given:
1. A directed graph G
2. A positive integer K
3. A source node S in graph G.

find the **minimum number of edges** to be added to graph G so that there is **simple path of length K from node S to all the other nodes** in the graph?

Does anyone know if this is a np complete problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set cover reduces to this for $K = 2$, so yes it is NP-hard.

The set cover problem can be formulated as this: given a graph $G$ with disjoint vertex sets $X$ and $Y$ and arcs going from $X$ to $Y$, choose a subset $X' \subseteq X$ of minimum cardinality such that for every element $y \in Y$, there is an arc going from $X'$ to $Y$.  Thus, $X'$ "covers" $Y$, and is called a covering set.

To reduce this to your problem, add your source vertex $s$, add another vertex $t$, add an arc between $s$ and $t$, and add every arc from $t$ to $X$.  It is not too hard to show that if there is a covering set $X'$ of size $k$, then adding $k$ arcs is enough to make $s$ at distance at most $2$ from every vertex
(add each arc from $s$ to $X'$).

Conversely, suppose that adding a set $A$ of $k$ arcs makes $s$ at distance at most $2$ from every vertex.  We use $A$ to find a covering set of size at most $k$.  If every arc of $A$ goes from $s$ to $X$, then the endpoint of the arcs of $A$ must form a covering set, as desired.  Suppose instead that there is some arc $(x, y)$ in $A$, for some $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.  Let $x' \in X$ such that $(x', y)$ is an arc of $G$ (we may assume $x'$ exists, otherwise the set cover instance is impossible).  In $A$, we may replace $(x, y)$ by $(s, x')$, and $s$ is still at distance at most $2$ from every vertex.  We may repeat this for every arc of $A$ from $X$ to $Y$.  Observe that we may also do this for every arc from $t$ to $Y$ in $A$, if any.  We may also handle arcs of $A$ from $Y$ to $Y$ in the same manner, then arcs of $A$ from  $s$ to $Y$, if any.  Note that there is no point in having arcs from $Y$ to $X \cup \{s, t\}$, and arcs from $X$ to $X$ can easily be replaced by an arc from $s$ to $X$, so this takes care of every possible type of arc.  After these operations, $A$ has only arcs of the form $(s, x)$ for $x \in X$, and the endpoints of $A$ must form a covering set.

Comment: Hey Manuel! Thanks for the response! I understood the first two paragraph, but the third one was not clear to me! can you explain it more?

Comment: OK, see if it is clearer now.  The details are a bit annoying, but hopefully the idea is there.

Comment: Thanks manuel but I think you understood the question wrong. We want to have SIMPLE PATH from node S to every other node with EXACT length of  K by just ADDING minimum number of edges!
And why is it always possible for every directed graph G to have two disjoint vertex sets X and Y with arcs going from X to Y?

Comment: All the paths of length 2 starting from $s$ in this reduction should be simple (if not, you would have to define simple).  A covering set corresponds to the set of arcs to add.  As for your question on the disjoint sets $X$ and $Y$, we're not saying here that every graph $G$ has this property.  These are instances that are coming from the set cover problem.  Your problem is difficult on these particular instances.